# problem with will_paginate with render json in rails 2.3.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am trying to upgrade my rails gem from 2.3.2 to 2.3.11. However, I got some problems with will_paginate 2.3.15 and render json back.

```
module WillPaginateHelpers
    WillPaginate::Collection.class_eval do
      alias :to_json_without_paginate :to_json

        def to_json(options = {})
          hash = { :current_page => current_page,
            :per_page => per_page,
            :total_entries => total_entries,
            :total_pages => total_pages,
            :items => to_a
          }

          hash.to_json(options)
        end
    end
end
```

Previously, the code above could work with:

```
@products = Product.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 20)
render :json => @products
```

However, with rails 2.3.11, it comes up with error "object references itself" unless i need to code this way: `render :json => @products.to_json`.
How to fix this? What happened with `render :json => @products`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added this to an initializer:

```
class WillPaginate::Collection
  def as_json options={}
    {
      :total_entries => self.total_entries,
      :current_page => self.current_page,
      :total_pages => self.total_pages,
      :per_page => self.per_page,
      :items => super
    }
  end
end
```